# Topology: if for every $A,B \in T$, either $A \subset B$ or $B \subset A$, then the arbitrary union of elements of T is an element of T

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $T$ is a collection of subsets of $X$, such that for  every $A,B\in T$, either $B \subset A$ or $A \subset B$, then $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \in T$

I know that $B\cup A=A$ if   $B \subset A$ and $B\cup A=B$  if $A \subset B$
but I don't know how to prove the above statement and I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: Consider the collection of closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, and choose a sequence of intervals $[a_n,b_n]$, with $\{a_n\}$ a decreasing sequence convergent to $a$, and $\{b_n\}$ an increasing sequence convergent to $b$.

Comment: @Aweygan You really should answer the question, this is a simple yet efficient counterexample!

Comment: ". . . then $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\in T$"?? What do the $A_i$ come from? Did you leave something out? Did you mean to assume that $A_i\in T$?

Comment: Let $I=X=\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots\},$ the set of all positive integers; for each $n\in\mathbb N$ let $A_n=\{1,2,\dots,n\},$ and let $T=\{A_n:n\in\mathbb N\}.$ Then for any $A,B\in T$ either $B\subseteq A$ or $A\subseteq B,$ but $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n=\mathbb N\notin T.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true.  Let $\{a_n\}$ be a strictly decreasing sequence in $\mathbb R$ convergent to some $a\in\mathbb R$, let $\{b_n\}$ be an increasing sequence in $\mathbb R$ convergent to some $b\in \mathbb R$, and put $T=\{[a_n,b_n]:n\in\mathbb N\}$.  Then $T$ satisfies all criterion, but $\cup T\notin T$.

Comment: You should restrict $T$ to only contain the intervals $[a_n, b_n]$, otherwise we have $[0,1], [1,2] \in T$ but $[0,1] \not\subset [1,2]$ or vice versa.

Comment: @Hetebrij Good point, thank you

Comment: Thanks!, i was excited about the hipotesis, but now i'm gonna try it with X as a finite set

Comment: @AlfredoHigueraMadrigal In that case you should have success.

Comment: You'd also want to say that your sequences are strictly decreasing and strictly increasing.

Comment: @martin.koeberl That's what I meant, but it's not required.  What is required is that for $\{a_n\}$ or $\{b_n\}$ (not necessarily both), there is a strictly monotonic subsequence.

Comment: Yes, you can also write that. You can even say it only for one. I also knew what you meant, but maybe not everyone else does. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the collection of intervals on the real line of the form $(-\infty,q)$, where $q$ is a rational number. This is a countable collection which is isomorphic to the rational numbers as far as ordering goes.

But clearly it isn't closed under arbitrary unions, since taking any irrational number $r$ and consider the intervals bounded by $r$ from this collection.

Perhaps a simpler example is as above, but taking $q$ to be any real number. Then the union of the whole collection is the real numbers, which is not a bounded interval.